# Creating a new Registery Key with a default string value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

What I am ultimately trying to do is either add an entirely new subkey with a name called "XtraFileLogging" with some default value, currently it's "NOTHING!!!", or I want to extract the value from the subkey named "XtraFileLogging".

**Why am I having to call SetValue after a call to SetKeyValue when trying to add an entirely new subkey?**

The following code works but it seems like I am using an extra step with a call to SetValue seeing as how SetKeyValue does the following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ey539x.aspx

```
CRegKey oRegKey;
bool setKeyWorked = false;
if (oRegKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\EXTRA\\PROG2\\CONFIG")) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    LPCTSTR keyName = _T("XtraFileLogging");
    LPCTSTR keysValue = _T("NOTHING!!!");

    if (oRegKey.SetKeyValue(keyName, keysValue) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        setKeyWorked = true;
        if (oRegKey.SetValue(keysValue, keyName) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            setKeyWorked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            setKeyWorked = false;
        }
    }
}
oRegKey.Close();
```

Why is it when i try either of the following SetKeyValue statements without the extra call to SetValue that the key doesn't show up?

```
if (oRegKey.SetKeyValue(keyName, keysValue) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    setKeyWorked = true;
}
```

Or

```
if (oRegKey.SetKeyValue(keyName, keysValue, keyName) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    setKeyWorked = true;
}
```

I even attach to the process and debug it and every time I can see that setKeyWorked is equal to true. Unfortunately without the extra call to SetValue afterwards the key never ends up getting created which I verified using regedit.

Comment: It seems like you're creating a key named N with value V, and then you create an item in that key, with name V and value N. Use `regedit` to check the result in the registry.

Comment: I do use regedit to verify that the key and value get added, and it only gets added when i add the SetValue call afterwards. @Cheersandhth.-Alf